# Sorting data frames with time in hours days months format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, rows

I have one data frame with time in columns but not sorted order, I want to sort in ascending order, can some one suggest any direct function or code for data frames sort time.

My input data frame:

| Time | data1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 month | 43.391588 |
| 13 h | 31.548372 |
| 14 months | 41.956652 |
| 3.5 h | 31.847388 |

Expected data frame:

| Time | data1 |
| --- | --- |
| 3.5 h | 31.847388 |
| 13 h | 31.847388 |
| 1 month | 43.391588 |
| 14 months | 41.956652 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need replace units to numbers first by [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) and then convert to numeric by [`pandas.eval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html), last use this column for sorting by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
d = {' months': '*30*24', ' month': '*30*24', ' h': '*1'}
df['sort'] = df['Time'].replace(d, regex=True).map(pd.eval)

df = df.sort_values('sort')
print (df)
        Time      data1     sort
3      3.5 h  31.847388      3.5
1       13 h  31.548372     13.0
0    1 month  43.391588    720.0
2  14 months  41.956652  10080.0
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly you have to assert the type of data you have in your dataframe.
This will indicate how you may proceed.
`df.dtypes`  or at your case `df.index.dtypes` .
Preferred option for sorting dataframes is  `df.sort_values()`

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.